# WordPress - Wrong jQuery version?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add some features to a site that I didn't build originally.

I am enqueueing jQuery correctly, I believe:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_register_script( 'main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/includes/main.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

My main.js file is pretty simple:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

  var header = jQuery('.site-header');
  var header_height = header.outerHeight;
  var scrolltop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();

  if (scrolltop >= header_height) {
    var header = jQuery('.site-header');
    header.addClass('not-fixed');
  }

console.log(header_height+','+scrolltop);

})
```

However, when I check the console for when scrolling it gives:

```
[cycle2] --c2 init--
main.js?ver=4.6.1:13 function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)},4
main.js?ver=4.6.1:13 function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)},32
main.js?ver=4.6.1:13 function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)},88
main.js?ver=4.6.1:13 function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)},152
main.js?ver=4.6.1:13 function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)},148
main.js?ver=4.6.1:13 function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)},112
```

And, my script doesn't work. It sure seems that a different library from some plugin is dominating my script. Any ideas people? I guess I could CDN another version, but I don't really want to load a million jQuery librarys.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: ugh, outerHeight isn't a function...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the `outerHeight()`  function

Change

```
var header_height = header.outerHeight;
```

To

```
var header_height = header.outerHeight();
```

What you are seeing in console is the function object...not what that function returns